# Should employees threaten resignation to get better benefits? If that seems to be the way in organization

Tags: colleagues, resignation, promotion

I'm seeing management giving employees more travel opportunity, better  packages, and/or promotion when employees hand in a resignation letter or if the organization suspects they are planning on leaving.  In my case though I see myself as a person of character, and won't use such tactics to climb the ladder or make jumps since money is not my sole motivator.

It really bothers me that unworthy people are getting more benefits and better opportunities while loyal ones are not cared for. By the way, I get what I expect, just that it's irritating me when someone with far less caliber gets more recognition.

My question is: If management behaviour is as such should honest/loyal employees change organization or change their strategy?

Finally, if this behavior is normal for management, what are ways to cope with this?

Comment: Threatening to resign is a very short-term strategy. It may work once, but more times than not, the company starts to look for a more loyal replacement.

Comment: what happens in the long term? are those employees who resign and get extra benefits still there a year later?

Comment: Well. I know of 2 one left for better job other got travel, promotion n  change of unit. We ideal want them to be fished out by org. thinks otherwise. We - colleagues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few reasons why I would never threaten an employer. For the most part, employers want loyalty from their employees.<sup>†</sup> Being disloyal can be seen as an slap in the face to them.

1. It will move me to the top of the "to be laid off" list.
2. I will (almost) never get any new benefits / promotions
3. It will often backfire.

If you want a raise or other perks, you can certainly ask for them. It will bolster your case if you can provide evidence as to why you deserve the increase, such as monetary savings, increased revenue, etc.

That being said, it sounds like the management in your company has turned into a codependent mess. If threatening to resign is *de regure* to getting raises, perks and promotions, then you'll need to play that game if you want those benefits.

### Life isn't fair

> *It really bothers me that unworthy people are...*

Just stop right there. You are getting yourself into a poisonous mindset that will **hurt you** in the end. Concentrate on what **YOU** can do to increase your own skills and value to your current (and any future) company. Resist the urge to waste your time on worrying that your coworkers are getting perks—something you have no control over and cannot change.

<sup>†</sup> Of course they will not reciprocate, so welcome to the wonderful world of work.

Comment: I expressed my discontent got supportive reply not concentrating on these anymore, Wanted to know if it is ok to wait than jump n juggle. Thanks helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Loyalty and honesty are not everything**

Promotions and benefits should neither be based off of threatening to quit nor based off of honesty/loyalty.  Benefits, raises, and perks should be rewards for employees that contribute to the company/organization and/or go above and beyond what is expected.  Promotions should be based off of skill, experience, and the question: can this person handle the extra responsibilities that come with the promotion?

Simply being loyal to a company and being honest should not entitle you to more travel opportunity, better packages.

If a company's culture does not align with yours and it is causing you irritation, then you are left with several options:

- Find a company that better aligns with your views
- Accept the company's culture as it is (not necessarily agreeing with it)
- Try and change the workplace's culture (very difficult)

Comment: It is unfortunate that u misread the question. I was getting my fair share but some didn't and some got way too much. I was unhappy with top management that it made me ask such q.

Answer (score 0):

We have many questions on this site regarding counter-offers when a employee tells management they are leaving. Employees want to know should I take the counter-offer. The general advice is that many times the terms of counter offer is either never fully met (that promised training never happens), or is just a delay. And the delay can be from other side: management uses the increase in pay to buy time to find a replacement, then terminates the current employee or forces them out; employees decide that the better offer hasn't solved the real problem and they start looking again.

We have some questions from people who want to use a real or fake job offer to get a better pay or benefits from their current employer.

You could be playing a dangerous game by attempting to game the system. They may decide that they don't want to make a counter offer, and now you have no job. They could decide that you have signaled that you are a short-timer and will now treat you as such.

why does management make these types of counter offers? Some companies do this routinely, others never make a counter-offer. It depends on what their goals are regarding turnover and their ability to find replacements. It will also depend on their experience when they make these counter-offers.

employees might be better off asking management what they need to do to get these better positions/benefits? That way they can decide what they need to do to get those positions.

In your situation if it bothers you that others get these benefits, you may be starting on the road to leaving the company. You might not be ready yet, but you could be soon. You may think that threatening to leave is the way to a better situation, but you may find out that those benefits don't solve the problem.